# Combining vim's fold and conceal feature

Tags: vim

I'm using vim's conceal feature to display my latex files in a somewhat more readable form.

Furthermore, I'm using the vim-latex plugin, which creates folds for the math environments which then show the label and the beginning of the content of the environment.

Example:
The math environment in plain latex code looks like this:

```
\begin{align}
   \xi = \cos \alpha
   \label{eqn:test}
\end{align}
```

Using the vim's conceal feature, it is displayed as

```
\begin{align}
   ξ = \cos α
   \label{eqn:test}
\end{align}
```

When vim now creates the fold, it displays as

```
+--  4 lines: align (eqn:test): \xi = \cos \alpha
```

My question is now:
Is it possible to get vim to apply the conceal to the description of the folds, so that it looks like below?

```
+--  4 lines: align (eqn:test): ξ = \cos α
```

Comment: +1 for showing conceal, which is completely new to me!

Comment: Never heard about conceal before this question! Thanks!

Comment: @Jonatan every time we `:h something`  we see conceal syntax and conceal highlighting. Because vim help ft has conceal syntax. E.g. `:h something` and then `V` then `jjjjjj...` until you see the conceal stuff. (for example, links)   vim help buffer has `cocu=nc` and `cole=2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the foldtext and conceal **could** be combined. But this needs to be implemented by yourself, following the conceal logic.

The option `foldtext` defines the text to display, when a fold was closed. The value of the option could be a vim function or expression. so we could do pretty much modification on the original text.

Conceal. usually it does: when X pattern matched, display Y instead of X. So we could write a function, read the foldstart line, check the conceal syntax patterns, if the line matches any, if True, then remove those matched part, and display the cchar. We set this function as value of `foldtext` option. Of course only for certain file type.

For highlighting, these two groups could be used for foldtext.

```
Folded      line used for closed folds
FoldColumn  'foldcolumn'
```

It is what I can think of. If someone could have some better/easier way to do it, I am glad to learn. for example some build-in function, which I don't know,  could help in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So basically, I'd have to write a filter for the the foldtext function that comes with the latex suite, and use that as the new foldtext. Is there a way to use vim's syntax matching on the string returned by a function or would I have to implement the whole matching myself?

Comment: @SimonL. as I wrote in the answer. AFAIK I don't think vim provides the thing out of box.

Comment: @SimonL. If you _really_ want it, you can have a background instance of Vim and then put your fold line in scratch buffer and capture the rendered characters.